# Python recursion changing parameter ONLY inside if

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion, recurrence

**[EDITED]**

I'm having a really strange error and I can't quite wrap my head around it. How is it possible that id is still 1 (it's initialized to 1 when recursion starts) inside the for statment.

```
    def recursive_read(root, id, cursor, database):
        if root.text is not None:
            cursor.callproc('add_node', (id, root.text))
            database.commit()
            #print('Adding element to db... ')
            id = id+1
        for elem in root.getchildren():
            recursive_read(elem, id, cursor, database)
```

**EDIT:**

This forms a perfect tree but unluckily it's not what I want. I want to "move" this indentation so child can reference correctly to parent, and for that I need id to increase only when element with text is encountered, so the problem remains.

```
def recursive_read(root, indent):
    if root.text is not None:
        print(' '*indent + '%s' % (root.text))
    for elem in root.getchildren():
        recursive_read(elem, indent+1)
```

What should I change so the id changes ONLY WHEN root.text is not None?

Comment: The code you have provided only modifies the value of id when `root.text is not None`. If thats not whats happening then this code snippet is not the error.

Comment: Are you expecting `id` to be changed after the recursive call?  Integers passed as parameters are immutable, so are not changed in the caller.  You should `return id` and `id = recursive_read(elem, id, cursor, database)`.

Comment: I wanted to increase id when text is not None and when it is not it should stay like the provided value

Comment: you sure the first call to recursive_read(), root.getchildren() returned anything? that is, you sure recursive_read() was really called more than once? Or once root.text is not None, recursive_read() got called again?

Comment: Yes, even 20k times I would say, as the print indicates... It goes on to the next element (root is divided into many elems (or let's say children)), afterwards those children go into the function. It enters the first if because it adds elements to database, still id is equal to 1.

Comment: so if you print out id before the for loop, you saw the value go above 1? then go back to 1?

Comment: @Shiping yes, that's exactly what's happening, see comment below and discussion under it.

Comment: @Shiping added additional code which does what is expected. Indents the text when element is found and forms a (correct) tree from my data.

Comment: @xxxxx i think i see your problem. you need to use id as a global variable, not as a parameter to the recursive function. i can explain more if you need it (but I think you'd see the cause yourself).

Comment: @Shiping Thanks, that was it, my bad

Comment: @xxxxx Oh i just explained a little more in my post upon your suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that id is a parameter passed to the recursive function, not a global variable. What ever changes to id in a call will only affect subsequent calls initialed from this call, not calls initiated from other calls.

For example, suppose at level one, if id has a value of 2 before the for loop, then each iteration of the loop will pass 2 as the value of id to recursive_read(). No matter how many levels the called recursive_read() will go down and change id many times, when it returns, id will still be 2 and the next call to recursive_read() in the loop will still have id passed with the value of 2.

Comment: Beware with globas, they [are evil] http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

returning the current value of ID seems a much better approach as  @cdarke suggested in  the comments